# Adding multiple objects to self closing div

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add multiple objects to one div.

Code

```
            var button1 = $('<button/>',{
                type: "button",
                class: "btn btn-defaultl btn-sm",
                html: span1
            });

            var button2 = $('<button/>',{   
                type: "button",
                class: "btn btn-defaultl btn-sm",
                html: span2
            });

            var h3 = $('<h3/>',{
                text: value.name
            })

            var inner_div = $('<div/>',{
                class: 'col-xs-8',
                html: h3.append(button1).append(button2)

            });
```

Forgive me for the naming please, this will be changed

**Goal**
I want to have a structure like this

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
   <h3></h3>
   <button1 ... />
   <button2 ... />
</div>
```

But the code puts everything inside each other now

```
<div class="col-xs-8">
   <h3>
        <button1 ... />
        <button2 ... />
    </h3>
</div>
```

Which jquery function should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can use [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add those elements directly to the div like

```
var inner_div = $('<div/>', {
    class: 'col-xs-8'
}).append(h3).append(button1).append(button2);
```

In your case you are adding the `button` elements are children of the `h3` then is adding the `h3` as a child of the `div`

Comment: is there a "difference" between using the after as suggested? is this "better" or more used?  (still learning student)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.append()` use `.after()`

```
var inner_div = $('<div/>',{
                class: 'col-xs-8',
                html: h3.after(button1).after(button2)

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending the button elements to the `h3` before the `h3` itself is appended. Use `after()` instead of `append()`.

```
 html: h3.after(button1).after(button2)
```

A better alternative however, is to create the containing `div` first, then append to it as other elements are created. Try this:

```
var $inner_div = $('<div/>', { class: 'col-xs-8' }).appendTo('body') // change 'body' as needed
    .append($('<h3/>', { text: value.name }))
    .append($('<button/>', {
        type: "button",
        class: "btn btn-defaultl btn-sm",
        html: span1
    }))
    .append($('<button/>',{   
        type: "button",
        class: "btn btn-defaultl btn-sm",
        html: span2
    }));
```

If the HTML you are creating gets more complicated, I would suggest looking in to using a templating plugin.

Comment: this looks good, going to change it, ty :). I need to convert all html/php pages (zend) to html/js only for using phonegap.